# Is it proper to cite a web page using embedded metadata for an APA paper?

Tags: citations, website

I saved the home page for the [Academic Libraries of Indiana](http://academiclibrariesofindiana.org/home/start) to Zotero, and it pulled back an author from the metadata embedded in the page.  After pulling up the source of the page, I found a meta field defined as "DC.Creator" (which, according to the comment above the metadata block is a Dublin Core element).  Given that the page itself doesn't display this person's name, is it appropriate to cite the page as authored by that person, or should the institution be named as author?  I suspect if I cited the page as written by the organization it wouldn't be considered wrong, but at the same time, knowing that metadata is there makes me feel odd not attributing the authorship to the defined (but somewhat hidden) author.

Answer (score 1):

Some large websites, assign responsibles for each page, so in the case of a question or need for update that person would handle it. This does not mean authorship in its academic sense. So if the page does not contain a scientific claim and you refer to that just as a web-page then it should be attributed to the university (or department?), I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with using the name from the embedded metadata. It's a little unusual but they've clearly made it available in some fashion, and intended it to be used - they wouldn't have marked it up as DC metadata if it was meant to be unknown!